# How to explicity cast a type to Interface at runtime

Tags: c#, types, casting

Using reflection, I have got all the types in the assembly. How can I cast the Type t to an ICommand if i know that it implements Interface "ICommand"

```
ICommand C;
foreach(Type t in asm.GetTypes())
{

    if (t.GetInterfaces()[0].Name is "ICommand")
    {
        C = (ICommand)t; //throws Exception here - Unable
                         //to cast to ICommand
       RootDir.AddCommand(C, t.Namespace.Split('.'));
    }
 }
```

An example of the Type I am trying to cast

```
public interface ICommand
{
    string HelpDescription { get; }
    void Execute(CommandClass CC);
}


class CurrentDir : ICommand
{
    public string HelpDescription => "Current Directory - Change current directory";

    public static explicit operator CurrentDir (Type T)
    {
        return new CurrentDir();
    }

    void ICommand.Execute(CommandClass CC)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

How should I implement this such that It can cast from System.Type to ICommand?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're trying to cast `t` which is of type `Type` to an `ICommand`, which it doesn't implement.

From the looks of your code what you need to do is create an instance of `t` and then cast it:

```
var obj = Activator.CreateInstance(t);
var C = (ICommand)obj;
```